# Convert SRTM DEM GeoTIFF to XYZ tiles

Tags: qgis, elevation, srtm, xyz-tiles

I have SRTM DEM of whole country covering large area. It takes too much time to load in to QGIS and freezes the system while zooming in and out.

Is there any way to use this SRTM as XYZ tile in QGIS, so I can get elevation value also, as rendering of XYZ tile is very fast in QGIS.

Comment: Have you built overviews to speed up the rendering?

Comment: First step is to use buildvrt for building a virtual mosaic. Gdal2tiles may do the job, or gdal_retile.py. Or convert the vrt into Cloud Optimized GeoTIFF with gdal_translate. However simply building the overviews should make zooming in and out fast if the map view is not very large and QGIS does not need to open dozens of DEM files.

Comment: See https://twitter.com/gdaltips/status/1390397918633414659 for overviews (give you GDAL recipe + how to see the overview pyramid in QGIS)

Comment: What do you mean by XYZ tile exactly?